# Do validation for email and mobile number for the same field(Edit Text) in android

Tags: android, android-layout

Do validation for email address and mobile number for the same field. I have only one edit text. This edit text needs to be validated for both email and mobile number. If the user inputs mobile number then proceed with mobile number validation, else if the user inputs email then proceed with email validation.

```
                    String EmailInputContent = emailInput.getText().toString();
                    // Toast.makeText(context, EmailInputContent, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                    String regexStr = "^[0-9]*$";


                    // Check for a valid email id.
                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(EmailInputContent) ){

                        // Toast.makeText(context, " Enter the Email address  in forgot password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        // emailInput.setError("Enter the Emial address");
                        emailInput.setError("** Please enter the Email or Mobile number");

                        //entriesValid== false;


                        //emailInput.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));

                    }
                    else if(emailInput.getText().toString().trim().matches(regexStr)){

                    }
                    else if (!isEmailValid(EmailInputContent)) {

                        //  Toast.makeText(context, " Email address is invalid in forgot password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        emailInput.setError("Email address is invalid ");
                        //emailInput.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_email));

                    }
                    else

                    {
                        Intent i=new Intent(getApplication(),LoginActivity.class);
                        //Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"test",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        ForgotPost("http://staging.rayaztech.com/flyonfly/app_forgotpassword");
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
```

Comment: Show us what you tried.

Comment: you will have to get the text from the edit text and will have to perform custom validation in ontextchangeListener something like this example http://www.tutorialsface.com/2015/10/android-validating-email-edittext-sample-example-methods-tutorial/ and please do some research and show here what you did before asking the question.

Comment: Use a regex for email validation. You'll find a ton, by googling.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `Pattern` package in Android to match the input validation for email and phone

Do like

```
private boolean checkValidation()
{
    String input = yourEditText.getText().toString();
    if(input.contains("@"))
    {
      return android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(input).matches();
    }
    else
    {
       return android.util.Patterns.PHONE.matcher(input).matches();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check if the user has entered '@' character.
If the text has '@' character in it then proceed with email checking, else check for phone.
Other way proceed if it has all the numbers in it, then phone checking. Else if anything other than a number is typed go for email checking as now phone is surely invalid.

Answer (score 0):

You can accept only numbers and phone number type using java code

```
EditText number1 = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.edittext); 
    number1.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER|InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE);
     number1.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789”));
      number1.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new InputFilter.LengthFilter(14)}); // 14 is max digits
```

This code will avoid lot of validations after reading input

Answer (score 0):

Email and phone validation on same edittext

Call this method inside Textwatcher Ontexchanged

```
private boolean checkValidMobileNumber(String s) {

if (s != null && s.length() == 10) {

  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(numberPattern);
   Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s.trim());
   Boolean flag = matcher.matches();

   if (flag) {
    binding.etMobile.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(10)});  
    }
   return flag;       
  }
 binding.etMobile.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(100)}
);   
return false;

}
```

For Email Validation use below code:

```
private boolean isValidEmail(String email) {
    Pattern pattern = Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS;
    return pattern.matcher(email).matches();
}
```

Call both the method on button click inside if condition